# overloading << for vector of pairs iterator

Tags: c++, vector

I am currently trying to use find_if to find an element in a vector of pairs.I have tried searching on google how to overload  << operator and it did give me a large amount of information on how to overload <<. It still left me confused how to achieve my goal. Below is the code i am using, i want to find the string supplied to the function in my vector of pairs s.

```
void Utils::findIt(string serchVal)
{
    vector<pair<string, HWND>>::iterator it = find_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
 [&serchVal](const pair<string, HWND>& element) { return element.first == serchVal; });

    cout << "find function found : " <<  *it << endl;

}
```

i have tried overloading the << operator like this.

```
template <typename T, typename D>
void operator<<(ostream& os, vector<pair(typename T, typename D)> &lst)
{
    cout << lst.begin.front();
}
```

i am not well versed in overloading functions and i am still new to vectors. so any help concerning this would be appreciated!

Comment: I find [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm) quite useful. You should return a reference to the stream. And inside the overload you should put something into the stream. `lst.begin.front();` is a noop, what did you expect this to do? In general you should post error messages (if any), desired and actual behaviour when you need help with fixing some code.

Comment: What - other than potentially being used to output the result - has overloading `operator<<()` got to do with finding a string?     The reason I ask is that your question is confused - and the unrelated concepts of finding a string and outputting something are somehow being combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to overload `operator<<` for a `std::vector<std::pair>` here as `std::find_if` will return the iterator pointing to the element found in the `std::vector`, which in this case will be an iterator to a `std::pair<std::string, HWND>`, to print this via a `std::ostream` you could use,

```
template<typename _Ty1, typename _Ty2>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& _os, const std::pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>& _p) {
    _os << _p.first << ' ' << _p.second;
    return _os;
}
```

if you want to go down the `operator<<` overloading route. However, printing elements of a `std::pair` is trivial anyway so overloading the insertion operator is not entirely necessary here.

Comment: with this i only get the error "binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::pair<std::string,HWND>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)" i am also up for suggestions to any other way to solve this

Comment: @mike I haven't done much Windows API programming but I can only assume that `HWND` has no overloaded `operator<<`, you would have to provide your own (if it even makes sense to in this case). If you just want to print the `std::string` of the `std::pair` then use `std::cout << (*it).first` in place of the statement in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The complete code for your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename D>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<std::pair<T, D>> &lst) {
    for (const auto &p : lst) {
        os << p.first << ", " << p.second;
    }
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs = { { 1, 2 }, { 5, 6 } };
    std::cout << pairs << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Step by step:

1. Usually it is better to return `std::ostream&` back to caller code so we change your `void operator<<` to `std::ostream& operator<<` prototype.
2. In the `operator<<` you just do what you want. If you `pair`'s data in the output - put it there:

   ```
   for (const auto &p : lst) {
       os << p.first << ", " << p.second;
   }
   ```